# How to query Overpass API with Postman?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, rest, overpass-turbo

I'm learning Open Street Map in order to try to retrieve a list of all cinemas in the world, in a country or in a city

I would like to know if I can do that with a REST query in Postman.

On [overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) I can see there is a way to do that. I see the informations I want to retrieve but I cannot tell how to create the query for Postman

[image]

On [harrywood.co.uk](http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/uixapi/xapi.html) it seems I can create the query but I must be doing something wrong. Dammit! I feel I'm so close!

[image]

I can see there are [other questions like mine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227177/getting-list-of-all-embassies-using-overpass-api), but they are not about Postman, so I don't really see how can I use those information.

But I know what I want to do is possible because I can see the outcome at [this URL](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/amenity=cinema#overview):

[image]

I now know that there are 23.743 cinemas in the worls and if it's possible I would like to retrieve those information.

Comment: cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724809/open-street-map-how-retrieve-amenity-in-postman

Comment: XAPI Builder is outdated these days, don't use it anymore. Follow the export steps provided by @scai below.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to start with a city first, rather than downloading data for the whole planet.

Comment: Reading the docs also helps: http://overpass-api.de/command_line.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arrived to query Overpass API with Postman this way:

```
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[amenity=cinema][bbox=-180,-90,180,90]
```

After 3 minutes and 13MB

[image]

Special tanks to @mmd that [linked on a comment](http://overpass-api.de/command_line.html) how to do it through command line and save it to an output file

```
wget -O target.osm http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[amenity=cinema][bbox=-180,-90,180,90]
```

Comment: Please don’t use the Xapi endpoint (like I mentioned before), it doesn’t support Overpass QL! Your follow up question https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/65281/overpass-api-rest-call-with-postman will not work with Xapi. Xapi is totally outdated these days.

Comment: Thank you @mmd, I see you know a lot about OSM. So what should I put instead of Xapi?

Comment: **use /api/interpreter instead like shown in the documentation**

Comment: Sorry @mmd, I tried but it's not working: `http://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=node[amenity=bank][bbox=-180,-90,180,90]`. Frankly, the documentation is poor around REST call. I hope my post will help more people. If you know how to call the API without Xapi please post an example of an URL. Thank you

Comment: You’re mixing xapi and overpass ql syntax here, again, start with overpass turbo and once you’re familiar with the language think about Postman. There’s plenty of documentation available: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL

Answer (score 5):

- If you want to learn fishing:
  Go to https://overpass-turbo.eu/
  Then enter the overpass query (QL/XML doesn't matter) that you like to check. Before running the query, open your browser network tab from its developers tools and then press run. You'll see how the data is posted.
- If you just want the fish:
  Open post man, create a POST request to `https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter`, and then if you want to use QL select x-www-form-urlencoded as the body type, add a key called `data` and set its value to be your QL query. If you want XML, select raw and set it to XML

Comment: This simply doesn't work. I sent a POST request to `https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:csv(::id,::type,"name")];
area[name="Bonn"];
nwr(area)[railway=station];
out;` and get an error `encoding error: Your input contains only whitespace.`

Comment: However, `GET` request seem to have worked.

Comment: No, it didn't work either: `{
    "version": 0.6,
    "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.55.7 8b86ff77",
    "osm3s": {
        "timestamp_osm_base": "2019-11-14T16:51:02Z",
        "timestamp_areas_base": "2019-11-14T15:16:02Z",
        "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
    },
    "elements": []
}`

Comment: Simply remove the whitespaces (after semicolons) from the query: `https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:csv(::id,::type,%22name%22)];area[name=%22Bonn%22];nwr(area)[railway=station];out;`

Answer (score 2):

At overpass-turbo.eu build your query, then simply go to Export -> Query -> OverpassQL for obtaining an [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) URL for your query.

Unfortunately I have absolutely no idea what Postman is.

Comment: Postman --> https://www.getpostman.com/